# using case for multiple parameters in where condition using sql

Tags: sql, select, case, using

I have a query as below. I want to return the case value for each filename(`alter.pdf`, `modify.pdf`) in rows.

However I am getting only case value for `alter.pdf`.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(P.[packageid]) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [VALUE]    
              FROM [Table_1] AS P    
              INNER JOIN    
       [Table_2] AS F on F.FileID = P.FileID  
        WHERE F.FileName IN('alter.pdf','modify.pdf')
```

Comment: Are there records for modify.pdf?

Comment: yes, the condition is if the count of package id for either pdf file is >0 I should get a case :1 or 0.

Comment: Can you show sample data and expected results? If you are only showing a `value` of 1 or 0, how do you know `modify.pdf` is not in the results?

Comment: To be more clear, I should get the result as Value
1
1

Comment: Please - sample data as DDL+DML and desired results. Also, tag the relevant rdbms (product and version).

Comment: Count() is an aggregate function and I don't see a "Group By" or any other aggregate statement that would produce a proper value for the Count() function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT  F.[FileName]
        , sum(CASE WHEN F.FileName = 'alter.pdf' THEN 1
               WHEN F.FileName = 'modify.pdf' THEN 1
               ELSE 0 
          END AS) [VALUE]             
FROM [Table_1] AS P    
INNER JOIN [Table_2] AS F on F.FileID = P.FileID  
WHERE F.FileName IN('alter.pdf','modify.pdf')
group by F.[FileName]
```